# Camel route dont´t delete file processed using "delete=true"

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using camel route to process a file to import items 
but when process finish don´t delete that file processed,

My route use **delete=true** that supposedly should delete my file

I am doing something wrong ?
I need to add something else so that my processed file is deleted?

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:{{main.path}}src/import/data/items?include=.*&amp;delete=true"/>       
        <setHeader headerName="organizationId"><constant>{{oid}}</constant></setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="documentType"><constant>items</constant></setHeader>     

        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="1" />                
            <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
            <to uri="direct:errorResponse" />
        </onException>

        <process ref="processCsvInitializeRoute" />
        <to uri="file:{{main.path}}/src/import/imports/?fileName=${header.fileName}" />

        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>$simple{in.header.fileExtension} == 'xls' || $simple{in.header.fileExtension} == 'XLS' || $simple{in.header.fileExtension} == 'xlsx' || $simple{in.header.fileExtension} == 'XLSX'</simple>
                <process ref="processXlsGetDataRoute" />
                <process ref="processXlsParsingRoute" />
                <choice>
                    <when>
                        <simple>$simple{in.body.validationResults.size} == 0</simple>
                        <setHeader headerName="map.file"><constant>{{main.path}}src//smooks//SMOOKS_BeanToCsvQuery.xml</constant></setHeader>
                        <process ref="processUploadRoute" />  
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <process ref="processXlsErrorRoute" />
                        <to uri="file:{{main.path}}/src/import/errors/?fileName=${header.resultFileName}" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>                       
            </when>
        </choice>
        <log message="Response: ${body}" />
    </route>
```

Comment: Thanks this issue already is resolved, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291346/file-componentapache-camel-delete-true-parameter-not-working-in-windows?answertab=active#tab-top                                                          but in summary the file was hanged for not closing an inputStream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File component(Apache camel) delete=true parameter not working in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291346/file-componentapache-camel-delete-true-parameter-not-working-in-windows)